# Hide Model in Ionic 3 not destroy

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, model, ionic3

Can I achieve the following scenario in Ionic 3.

I have a page and a button is opening a model. I don't want the model to destroy on close. Is there a way I can hide it so it contains all the data fetched and if I open it again it should display with the previous data.

Comment: You can use a state management library like ngrx to keep internal state while your application is running. The data fetched via API will be available in the store and your modal is able to access it every time you open/create it and the data is displayed immediatly.

Comment: You have raised a good point.But Op's use case is different. He is asking this `I don't want the model to destroy on close`. On that use case nothing to do with the `ngrx` right @David

Comment: He asks for "not destroying" it because thats probably the way he wants/thinks to solve the underlying problem which is displaying data that has already been fetched previously. But yes you're right it does not solve the exact question which is why I added it as a comment :-)

Comment: Yep, Me too really like to learn `ngrx` with `Ionic`. Do you know any good resources about it? Free or paid. @David

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510) is kind of the bible when learning ngrx, [this](https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b) and [this](https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5) are also very good articles. But the most important thing is to work with it, once you _really_ understood the concept its not hard to use it when you already know Angular and RxJS.

Comment: Oh.. Awesome. Thanks a lot :) @David

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. The discussion is usefull. I am also interested to know more about `ngrx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to destroy it. Otherwise, Ionic's navigation system won't work as expected.But you can easily load that modal's `data` again either using `navParams` or `Storage` module.